# for loop in django templates not working as expected

Tags: python, django, for-loop, iteration, rendering

I am creating a django app and am iterating through the images list. I've been at it for hours to no avail. I looked everywhere for help and still couldn't fix it. I successfully got the POST request with ajax and when I print it to the console the images sources are there in the list. But, upon iterating it in the django templates, it doesn't show up. It's funny because it does show up when I click the buy button for that request. Also, I am creating a bookmarklet that upon clicking will send the data of the URL of the current page to views.py. I am using that add the images data src into the list.

base.html (template)

```
<body>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% load static %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/onload.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <img width='100px' src="https://i.ibb.co/37ybzSD/neom-V1-NTz-Srn-Xvw-unsplash.jpg">
    <img src="https://i.giphy.com/media/tsX3YMWYzDPjAARfeg/giphy.webp">
    {% load socialaccount %}
    <h1>Billionaire Shopping Game</h1>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }} !</p>
    <a href="logout">Logout</a>
    {% else %}
    <a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}">Login with Google</a>
    {% endif %}
    
    <a href="javascript:(function() {let script = document.createElement('script'); script.src = '{% static '/js/bookmarklet.js' %}'; document.body.appendChild(script);})();">Bookmarklet</a>
    <a href="javascript: (() => {alert('Hello');})();">Helo alert</a>
    <img width="100px" src="{% static 'images/heart.png' %}">
    <div>
        <form method="POST" action="/">
            
            <label for="url_link">Item Link:</label>
            <input type="text" id="url_link" name="url_link" required>
            <button type="submit">BUY</button>
        </form>
            <!-- {% for image in images %}
            <img src="{{ image }}">
            {% endfor %} -->

        {% for book in bookimgs %}
            <!-- <img src="{{ book }}"> -->
            {{ book }}
        {% endfor %}


    </div>
    <p>Hello. This is Hoko Le.</p>
    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
</body>
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    images1 = []
    images2 = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        homeurl = request.POST.get('url_link')
        bookurl = request.POST.get('url')
        if homeurl != None and homeurl != '':
            rh = requests.get(homeurl, headers=HEADERS)
            soup = bs(rh.content, "lxml")
            images11 = soup.find_all('img',{"src":True})
            images2.clear()
            for image in images11:
                images1.append(image['src'])
        elif bookurl != None and bookurl != '':
            rb = requests.get(bookurl, headers=HEADERS)
            soupb = bs(rb.content, 'lxml')
            images22 = soupb.find_all('img',{"src":True})
            images2.clear()
            for image in images22:
                images2.append(image['src'])
                print(image['src'])
            print('images2 arr ')
            print(images2)
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'bookimgs': images2})
```

bookmarklet.js

```
    function initMyBookmarklet() {
        (window.myBookmarklet = function() {
            // your JavaScript code goes here!
            // window.open("/", "popup", "width=500,height=300");
            const element = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
            element[0].innerHTML = window.location.href;
            const csrftoken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;
            $.ajax({
                url: '',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    url: window.location.href,
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken
                }
            });
        })();
    }
```

I am not adding all my code because it is a lot.

Comment: `if homeurl != None and homeurl != ''` When this condition is true, `images2` will be an empty list in the view code, and therefore `bookimgs` is an empty list in the template.

Comment: That' strange, why would that be? I tried removing ```homeurl != None``` and it still didn't work. How can there be a workaround that?

Comment: _That' strange, why would that be?_ Because that code block calls `images2.clear()` and does not add anything else to it, so it remains an empty list when the template is rendered.

Comment: The thing is the list isn't empty because I printed the list and srcs would be there.

Comment: The print statement is in the `else` block, not the block I mentioned.  If you're seeing the print output, then the first `if` block was not true.

Comment: The `url_link` input item on the form has a `required` tag, so I would expect the first `if` block to always be true...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but I’m trying to get images2 to show not images1. I already got images1 to work.

Comment: The only way I see that `images2` would be empty is as I already said, when `if homeurl != None and homeurl != ''` is true.

Comment: I have removed that and I still get an empty list like this ```[]```. When I console.log the length of the array it actually shows length of 2 which it should but when I do the actual contents it shows ```[]```

Comment: _I have removed that_ Removed what exactly?

Comment: _When I console.log the length of the array_ What variable, exactly, are you using with console.log ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255700/discussion-between-hoko-a-and-john-gordon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error and using ChatGPT (thanks openAI) I was able to fix the bug!! I had to use sessions to store the data because it kept refreshing the server since I was running it in the python terminal.

What ChatGPT said:
It seems like the issue might be related to the timing of when the bookmarklet is invoked and when the page is being rendered.

When you click the bookmarklet, it triggers an asynchronous action (AJAX request) to fetch images from the server. However, when the page is initially rendered or refreshed, the images might not be available immediately.

To address this, you can modify your Django view to handle both cases:

1. When the page is initially loaded or refreshed, return the page with the existing data.
2. When the AJAX request is made after invoking the bookmarklet, return the updated data.

bookmarklet.js

```
function initMyBookmarklet() {
        (window.myBookmarklet = function() {
            // your JavaScript code goes here!
            // window.open("/", "popup", "width=500,height=300");
            const element = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
            element[0].innerHTML = window.location.href;
            const csrftoken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;
            $.ajax({
                url: '',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    url: window.location.href,
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken
                },
                success:function(data){ 
                    window.myBookmarklet.imagesCallback(data.bookimgs);
                }
            });
            
            
        })();
```

Added success function with the imagesCallback.

views.py

```
def home(request):
    images1 = []
    images2 = []
    bookimgs = []
    if request.method == 'POST':

        images2 = []
        homeurl = request.POST.get('url_link')
        bookurl = request.POST.get('url')
        # if homeurl != None and homeurl != '':
        #     rh = requests.get(homeurl, headers=HEADERS)
        #     soup = bs(rh.content, "lxml")
        #     images11 = soup.find_all('img',{"src":True})
        #     images1.clear()
        #     for image in images11:
        #         images1.append(image['src'])
        if bookurl:
            rb = requests.get(bookurl, headers=HEADERS)
            soupb = bs(rb.content, 'lxml')
            images22 = soupb.find_all('img',{"src":True})
            for image in images22:
                images2.append(image['src'])
            
            images2 = [image['src'] for image in images22]
            request.session['images2'] = images2
            return JsonResponse({'bookimgs': images2})
    
    bookimgs = request.session.get('images2', [])
    print('outside')
    print(bookimgs)
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'bookimgs': bookimgs})
```

Returned a JsonResponse for images2.

home.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block content %} {% csrf_token %}
<form method="POST" action="/">
  <label for="url_link">Item Link:</label>
  <input type="text" id="url_link" name="url_link" required />
  <button type="submit">BUY</button>
</form>
<!-- {% for image in images %}
    <img src="{{ image }}">
    {% endfor %} -->

{{ bookimgs }} {% for book in bookimgs %}
<img src="{{ book }}" />
{{ book }} {% endfor %}
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.myBookmarklet = window.myBookmarklet || {};
  window.myBookmarklet.imagesCallback = function (bookimgs) {
    // Update the page with the fetched images
    console.log("Fetched images:", bookimgs);
    // You might want to update the page here
  };
</script>

{% endblock content %}
```

Had to add definition for the imagescallback in the html template.

Answer (score 0):

these might be the cause of the problem:

- in views.py it seems that you `images1` list used to store images for `homeurl` and `images2` list is used to store images for `bookurl` but you are clearing `images2` for both of them.

```
def home(request):
    images1 = []
    images2 = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        homeurl = request.POST.get('url_link')
        bookurl = request.POST.get('url')
        if homeurl != None and homeurl != '':
            rh = requests.get(homeurl, headers=HEADERS)
            soup = bs(rh.content, "lxml")
            images11 = soup.find_all('img',{"src":True})
            images1.clear() # changed images2 to images1
            for image in images11:
                images1.append(image['src'])
        elif bookurl != None and bookurl != '':
            rb = requests.get(bookurl, headers=HEADERS)
            soupb = bs(rb.content, 'lxml')
            images22 = soupb.find_all('img',{"src":True})
            images2.clear()
            for image in images22:
                images2.append(image['src'])
                print(image['src'])
            print('images2 arr ')
            print(images2)
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
    print(images2) #make sure images 2 has the correct data
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'bookimgs': images2})
```

- in `bookmarklet.js` make sure that the URL in the `$.ajax` request is correctly set to the endpoint where the ``` home`` view is handling the POST request and make sure that image URLs are correctly populate in the ``` images2``` list before being passed to the template.

```
 function initMyBookmarklet() {
        (window.myBookmarklet = function() {
            // your JavaScript code goes here!
            // window.open("/", "popup", "width=500,height=300");
            const element = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
            element[0].innerHTML = window.location.href;
            const csrftoken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    url: window.location.href,
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken
                },
                success:function(data){ 
                    window.location = window.location.href;
                }
            });
        })();
    }
```

Comment: I have removed ```images1.clear()``` and ```images2.clear```. I also printed the list to the terminal before rendering and they were populated. Didn’t work. I’m thinking maybe it’s because I am using the bookmarklet to send the request instead a form.

Comment: when you're making AJAX request from the bookmarklet it's essential to handle response appropriately, since AJAX request is asynchronous the page won't automatically refresh when request completes. you can redirect the user to the same page after the AJAX request is completed, this way the updated context will be rendered

Comment: How would I redirect? Do you mean the success key?

Comment: this will do the trick:
 success:function(data){ 
                    window.location = window.location.href;
                }

Comment: I think I figured it out. I printed array outside of the if blocks right before the render and it showed up as empty. It must be the scope. How can I make images2 keep the appended values outside of the if and else blocks?

Comment: I think images2 is already defined outside the if block though. I still think it is a scope issue. I tried making images2 a global variable as well and it still didn't work. Btw I used the success function too.

Comment: Ok it's actually not the scope that is the problem. I printed the list before the return render and it did show up with the correct values. However, when the page reloaded, the list that got printed out showed up as empty. So I think it's the reload and bookmarklet problem.

Comment: Ok, I can't believe it but I figured out the problem with ChatGPT, haha.